# How to iterate Python list and delete similar element?

Tags: python, arrays, list, iteration

I have a list of dictionary which represents the centre and radius of circle.

```
[{centre:(743,1105), radius: 41},
 {centre:(743, 1106), radius: 48},
 {centre:(899, 1443), radius: 48},
 {centre:(900, 1442), radius: 40}]
```

I want to remove the closed circles based on the position of x axis. If the difference of x axis of two circles is greater than 0 and less than 3, the one whose radius is bigger will be removed.

```
def takeXAxis(input):
    return input['centre'][0]


def sortCircles(circleDetails):
    circleDetails.sort(key=takeXAxis)


def removeClosedCircle(circleDetails):
    newCircleDetails = []
    for i in range(len(circleDetails)):
        j = i + 1
        for j in range(len(circleDetails)):
            ...
```

I am very new to Python and don't know how to finish it.

### Added

This is result I am hoping to get:

```
[{centre:(743,1105), radius: 41},
 {centre:(900, 1442), radius: 40}]
```

Each of the element will be compared. For example:

0<=|743 - 743|<=3, 48 > 41, therefore the second one will be removed.

|743 - 899| >= 3, |743 - 900 | >= 3, nothing will happen here.

0<=|899 - 900|<=3, 48 > 40, therefore the third one will be removed.

**Updated**

This is the solution I come up with. But it's very slow. Anyone knows how to optimise it?

```
def takeXAxis(input):
    return input['centre'][0]

def removeaAdjacentCircle(circleDetails):
    circleDetails.sort(key=takeXAxis)
    newCircleDetails = []
    indexOfRemovedCircle = []
    for i in range(0, len(circleDetails)):
        if i in indexOfRemovedCircle:
            continue
        for j in range(i + 1, len(circleDetails)):
            delta = abs(circleDetails[i]['centre'][0] - circleDetails[j]['centre'][0])
            if 0 <= delta <= 3:
                if circleDetails[i]['radius'] - circleDetails[j]['radius'] >= 0:
                    indexOfRemovedCircle.append(i)
                else:
                    indexOfRemovedCircle.append(j)

    for i in range(0, len(circleDetails)):
        if i in indexOfRemovedCircle:
            continue
        newCircleDetails.append(circleDetails[i])

    return newCircleDetails
```

Comment: `difference of x axis of two circles is greater or less than 3` , This condition will cover all the records. Are you sure this is correct?  At the end you'll just be left with `1` record.

Comment: @MayankPorwal the result will be [{centre:(743,1105), radius: 41},
 {centre:(900, 1442), radius: 40}].The first circle has same x as the second one. 0<=|743 - 743| <= 3. The last two: 0<= |899 - 900| <= 3

Comment: So you don't want each element of the list to be compared against each of them again? It looks like you want to get pairs of them in order?

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal I want each of them to be compared. I was thinking to use a double for loop but I don't know how to write it.

Comment: Are you sure about your expected output? Because you have contradictory statements in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `itertools.combinations()`. I believe it's more efficient than nested loops.

```
import itertools

my_list = [
    {'centre':(743,1105), 'radius': 41},
    {'centre':(743, 1106), 'radius': 48},
    {'centre':(899, 1443), 'radius': 48},
    {'centre':(900, 1442), 'radius': 40}
]

for a, b in itertools.combinations(my_list, 2):

    # only need to do something if the diff is in range..
    if abs(a['centre'][0] - b['centre'][0]) <= 3:

        # check the radius, if bigger, remove it, else remove the other.
        if a['radius'] > b['radius']:
            my_list.remove(a)
        else:
            my_list.remove(b)

print my_list
```

I have put comments to make it clear. Feel free to ask if you need to know anything.

Hope it will help :)